# When to use char field in a data class

Tags: c#, data-structures

Say I have a `Currency` class

```
public class Currency
{
    string Name;   // eg "US Dollars"
    string Symbol; // eg "$" 
    decimal Rate;  // eg 1.7
}
```

So, symbol is $, £, ..etc i.e. it's going to be a single character.

I used `string` simply because it makes translation to/from views easier, but is there any reason why I should be using `char`? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a `char` field instead of a `string`? Or is this a case like `byte`/`int` where you should basically always prefer `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you use `char`:

- It's *guaranteed* to be exactly a single character, and that's obvious to the developer (probably the biggest "pro" for `char`)
- It can never be null (although it could be U+0000)
- You won't be able to handle characters which aren't in the Basic Multilingual Plane

I don't know if any of those are important to you.

Answer (score 6):

Not all currency symbols are a single character: [Symbols List](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php).

Answer (score 3):

> Or is this a case like byte/int where you should basically always prefer int.

First off, I would argue that there are valid uses for `byte`.  `byte` takes less space than int - if you only need a `byte`, use a `byte`.

`System.Char` has a couple of advantages to `string`, in the right case.  First, its a single, immutable value type.  This is more efficient if you only need a single character.

In addition, using a `char` in your API makes it impossible to put more than one character into that field.  This may eliminate or simplify some of the validation required.

If it truly makes sense that you'd only ever want a single `char`, I'd say to use a `char`.  It simplifies the code (less validation), makes it more efficient (less memory as you don't have another object reference), and most importantly, expresses the intent more clearly, since you're saying "I just want one character here."

Comment: I was under the impression that byte was basically padded to int internally on 32/64 bit windows anyway?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: What gave you that impression?  That may be true *in some cases*, but not always.

Comment: Of course the problem with byte is all too often people are wrong when they think "This value will never be more than 255". I've seen it real world too many times to count. So while byte has valid uses you had better be really sure.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, the main exception to this is when you're dealing with a byte[].

Comment: @Kevin: True - it really depends on why you want a byte.  However, if you do, it's often useful.

Comment: @Reed - Absolutely I'd scream if they tried to take it out of the language. But I also occasionally scream at developers who use a byte as a small int to save space and now we have to break everything because we need a bigger range. We have a standard that an int is the default and you need to justify using anything smaller.

Answer (score 1):

string is acceptable here, you just have to ensure that the string always contains only 1 character, which means a little extra code on that end to prevent exceptions.  Really, you can pick your poison here.